# android eclipse can't see layer-list in Graphical Layout

Tags: android, xml

i'm trying to build a layer-list of 2 images and to see it in the Graphical layout in eclipse in order to see that it came correctly...
for some reason i get an error

this is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/picuser" 
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"/>

</layer-list>
```

this is my error:

```
NOTE: This project contains Java compilation errors, which can cause rendering failures  
for custom views. Fix compilation problems first.

com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- item (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- layer-list (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
```

Comment: where is the open tag for the layer-list?

Comment: weird.. i could swear it was there.. i've fixed it

Comment: The Graphical Layout feature inside of eclipse is somewhat wonky, especially with custom views. Have you tried running it on a device to see if it shows properly?

Comment: actually no, but i really need to see it before in order to design it right.. otherwise it's gonna be a real mess to run the application for each change...

Comment: ok actually when i'm adding it to my ImageView it works..
but how can i change the size of each layer ?